# web api: get the request origin

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, request-headers

I am testing a web api and I am setting the From header in the request with Postman, like this:
[image]

But in my controller, when I evaluate `this.Request.Headers.From`, I'm getting a false result:

[image]

But when I am evaluating only the Request.Headers and I'm scrolling to the `ResultView`, I see that U have a header with the key From.

[image]

So what's the point of the member `From` from the `this.Request.Headers.From`?

Comment: do you mean `this.Request.Headers["From"]`?

Comment: when I'm evaluating this, I'm getting the error Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'HttpRequestHeaders'

Comment: try calling `.GetValues`

Comment: if I use this.Request.Headers.GetValues("From") I am getting the desired value. But my question was what's the point of the member From from the this.Request.Headers.From?

Comment: you'll have to look at the documentation and/or source code.

Comment: I did looked and it's saying: Gets or sets the value of the From header for an HTTP request. But I was expecting to find here the value that I set in Postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `From` header is standardized to an email address. Likely the .NET code is excluding it since it is not an email address.

Consider using a different header.